# Where are Adwaita, HighContrast and HighContrastInverse GTK themes located in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: themes, gtk

Where are Adwaita, HighContrast and HighContrastInverse GTK themes located in Ubuntu 18.04?

When I opened gnome tweaks in Ubuntu 18.04, I found these 3 themes but could not find the location.

Comment: They're are built into "GNOME". They're not separate themes in the conventional sense.

Comment: @Bose hi, thanks for reply. Means cant i remove them from system? I dont want them to show up when i choose GTK themes from gnome tweaks. I successfully removed other GTK themes which are in usr/share/themes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> GTK+ includes the Adwaita and HighContrast themes

From https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/CustomStyle and https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/tree/master/gtk/theme

Basically, Adwaita and the High Contrast theme are now part of [GTK+](https://www.gtk.org/) (the GIMP Toolkit) and no longer provided as separate themes as Ambiance or Radiance are.

In [a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041208/where-are-adwaita-highcontrast-and-highcontrastinverse-gtk-themes-located-in-ub/1041211#comment1696456_1041211) to this answer ,there is a mention of `gnome-themes-extra` with a link to https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/gnome-themes-extra/filelist

The referenced package list has:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines/libadwaita.so
/usr/share/doc/gnome-themes-extra/NEWS.gz
/usr/share/doc/gnome-themes-extra/README.md
/usr/share/doc/gnome-themes-extra/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/gnome-themes-extra/copyright
```

In other words, this package does provide `Adwaita`, but only for `gtk2` applications.

`apt show gnome-themes-extra` has:

```
Description: Adwaita GTK+ 2 theme — engine
 This is the version of Adwaita, the standard GNOME theme, for the
 GTK+ 2.x toolkit.
 .
 The GTK+ 3.x version is already included in libgtk-3-0.
 .
 This package contains the Adwaita theme engine.
```

In short,there's no way to remove Adwaita or High Contrast themes without removing `libgtk-3-0` itself which will take out a host of applications depending on `libgtk-3-0`.

You can *simulate* what will happen by using `-s` for ensuring a simulation. Because it's a simulation, there's no need for sudo:

```
apt purge -s libgtk-3-0
```

The exact output will depend on what you have on your system.

Comment: Seems to be in [`gnome-themes-extra`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/gnome-themes-extra/filelist). Given the `-extra` name, it might be removable without too much breakage. It's only a "recommended" dependency of `gnome-session`, for example.

Comment: @muru I think that's for gtk2 only.